# Implicit return in a javascript class method

Tags: javascript

Suppose I have this code:

```js
class AuthService {
  loginWithEmailAndPassword(email, password) {
    return apolloClient.mutate({});
  }
}

export default new AuthService();
```

is there a modern way to write `loginWithEmailAndPassword` to have an implicit return?

Comment: You can use an arrow function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, using the newer [public class fields](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Public_class_fields) feature, you can add the function to your instance.

```js
class AuthService {
  loginWithEmailAndPassword = (email, password) => (
    { email, password }
  )
}

const authService = new AuthService()
console.log(authService.loginWithEmailAndPassword('x@y', 'Password!'))
```

Note that there's a couple differences when you do this:

- Arrow functions automatically bind the "this" value whereas normal functions do not (in general, this is a good thing anyways)
- This function will be added onto the instance, not the prototype. This has important consequences if you expect others to be inheriting your class.

An example of the second point:

```js
class BaseClass {
  f = () => 2
}

class SubClass extends BaseClass {
  f() {} // Doesn't work - this won't shadow f() from the parent class
  f = () => super.f() // Doesn't work. This overrides f() from the parent class, so you can't access it's super method.
}
```

If you're not yet able to use this syntax, you can always create these functions in your constructor, like this:

```js
class AuthService {
  constructor() {
    this.loginWithEmailAndPassword = (email, password) => (
      { email, password }
    )
  }
}

const authService = new AuthService()
console.log(authService.loginWithEmailAndPassword('x@y', 'Password!'))
```

Comment: apolloClient.mutate returns a promise, I'm getting errors with this syntax, that's also why I'm asking

Comment: It should work, even if it returns a promise. This syntax is fairly new, so you need to make sure your platform supports it, otherwise, you would get a syntax error. You can check the browser compatibility table at the bottom of this page: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Public_class_fields

Comment: why are you using `{ email, password }` as return value? it is destructuring or a weird object?

Comment: `{ email, password }` is just shorthand for `{ email: email, password: password }`, i.e. I was just making the dummy function return an object that contained the parameters that were passed in.